# Fluid divs in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html, fluid

i just want to do something that if the resolution is changed, div's structure will be changed too. How to do this? What's the name of this kind operations? Thanks.
[image: fluid divs]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to make a responsive design.

This is supported out of the box in Bootstrap 3, in Bootstrap 2.x you need to just add in an extra css file - you can read more here:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive